# Averaging values across certain groups in Stata

Tags: stata

EDITED, see below.

I possess a transaction-level data set. Each observation is a sales transaction of a brand that took place at a specific store. One such transaction contains brand information of a product purchased and cents per ounce of product paid. And we can clearly distinguish whether this transaction took place at store #1, 2, 3, ..., 10: there are 10 stores overall. The data set is highly unbalanced, meaning that each store has a varying amount of transactions and available brands. Some stores have 100,000 transactions, some 60,000, etc.

My goal is to get a general idea about price level of each store by calculating average price per ounce across those transactions. If we average all transactions within each store, we can get a distorted picture about the overall price level since we are not considering exactly the same product mix across all the stores.

Thus, I need to generate a small table, separate from my data set, that will calculate average prices of those brands that are sold at all available stores. If a certain brand was not sold even at one of the stores, this transaction must be disregarded for the calculation purposes.

The raw data set would look something like:

```
brand   cents/oz    store
BrandA    9          1
BrandB    10         1
BrandC    6.5        1

BrandA    1          2
BrandB    2          2

BrandA    5          3
BrandB    6          3
BrandC    6.5        3
```

By following my instructions, we will have this:

```
store     avecents
  1          (9+10)/2=9.5 
  2          (1+2)/2=1.5
  3          (5+6)/2=5.5
 etc..
```

For each `avecents` calculation we include Brand A and Brand B only since they occur in each store. Brand C is disregarded at all since it was not sold at store 2.

**EDITED based on Dr. Cox's feedback:**

Here is a sample data set that contains brand prices from 3 distinct stores, `1085053`, `1084590`, and `1091828`. If we use the code `egen tag = tag(brand store)` provided by Dr. Cox, Stata will, indeed, tag distinct brands within each store.  But with the code `egen nstores = total(tag), by(store)`, Stata will only count a number of the distinct brands within each store, where `nstores=3`. Thus, the third code `table brand store if nstores == 3, c(mean price)` is not valid since the column `nstores` contains brand count. You can try this code:

```
clear
set more off
input str8 store str30 brand cenoz
1085053 SIERRA_NEVADA_PALE_ALE 9.715278
1085053 MILLER_HIGH_LIFE 5.319445
1085053 BACARDI_SILVER_MOJITO 9.013889
1085053 REDHOOK_ESB 9.430555
1085053 SMIRNOFF_ICE_GREEN_APPLE_BITE 9.360121
1085053 BIG_SKY_MOOSE_DROOL_BROWN_ALE 9.708333
1085053 WOODCHUCK_DRAFT_CIDER_DARK 8.872066
1085053 GRAIN_BELT_PREMIUM 6.937501
1085053 BACARDI_SILVER_MOJITO 9.013889
1085053 REDHOOK_ESB 9.430555
1084590 SAND_CREEK_SEASONAL 10.40278
1084590 MOLSON_CANADIAN 8.180555
1084590 NEWCASTLE_BROWN_ALE 8.256945
1084590 MICHELOB_GOLDEN_DRAFT_LIGHT 5.087963
1084590 SIERRA_NEVADA_PALE_ALE 12.63393
1084590 MILLER_HIGH_LIFE 6.013889
1084590 BACARDI_SILVER_MOJITO 9.020833
1084590 REDHOOK_ESB 7.625
1084590 SMIRNOFF_ICE_GREEN_APPLE_BITE 4.854167
1084590 BIG_SKY_MOOSE_DROOL_BROWN_ALE 12.48611
1091828 SIERRA_NEVADA_PALE_ALE 13.37798
1091828 MILLER_HIGH_LIFE 6.243055
1091828 SIERRA_NEVADA_PALE_ALE 13.37798
1091828 MILLER_HIGH_LIFE 6.243055
1091828 BACARDI_SILVER_MOJITO 8.319445
1091828 REDHOOK_ESB 6.590278
1091828 SMIRNOFF_ICE_GREEN_APPLE_BITE 5.782407
1091828 BIG_SKY_MOOSE_DROOL_BROWN_ALE 12.48611
1091828 MILLER_LITE 6.590278
1091828 BUD_LIGHT 5.895833
end

egen tag = tag(brand store) 
egen nstores = total(tag), by(store) 
table brand store if nstores == 3, c(mean cenoz)
collapse price if nstores == 3, by(brand store)
```

Comment: Questions without code are widely considered off-topic here. The site is not really about "what is good code for this?" but "what is wrong with my code?" I have answered this but add this comment nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each brand we require that it has been sold in all stores. This problem has been much discussed in Stata in more general terms as counting distinct observations. If we tag each distinct store-brand combination just once (tags are 0 or 1)

```
 egen tag = tag(brand store)
```

and then add tags across brands

```
 egen nstores = total(tag), by(brand)
```

then a brand is sold in all 10 stores if and only if `nstores == 10`. So the means you want are tabulated by

```
 table brand store if nstores == 10, c(mean cenoz)
```

and put in a reduced dataset by

```
 collapse cenoz if nstores == 10, by(brand store)
```

EDIT: A bug was fixed above.

Comment: Thank you! Please see the edited section of my question.

Comment: Adding some realistic data was helpful. Please try the revised code.

Comment: Dr. Cox, thank you very much for this feedback. The edited version works very well. I was able to identify a set of brands sold at all the stores in my data set of 700,000 observations.